# Is there a way to dynamically bind properties /variables to objects in C# WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I am writing myself a small Tool that helps me binding Joysticks for Flight simulators. As each axis has to be bound separately in the game, this i want to solve with my tool on a high level.
Long story short, I need to read in text files with data which tells the tool how many planes there currently exist and if i want to have the joystick bind also for that plane.

So in order for the user to tell if his profile applies also to this he needs to hit a checkbox or not.
So creating headers and the columns at runtime is no issue and can be done with this.

```
void InitDGSelected()
   {
     DataGridTextColumn IdTxtColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
     IdTxtColumn.Header = "ID";
     IdTxtColumn.Binding = new Binding("ID");
     DGAdded.Columns.Add(IdTxtColumn); //DGAdded is the DataGrid
     for(int i=1; i<MainStructure.Planes.Length; ++i)
     {
         DataGridCheckBoxColumn pcbc = new DataGridCheckBoxColumn();
         pcbc.Header = MainStructure.Planes[i];
         pcbc.Binding = new Binding(MainStructure.Planes[i]);
         pcbc.IsReadOnly = false;
         DGAdded.Columns.Add(pcbc);
     }    
   }
```

However populating it with Data is where my issue starts.
WPF needs property objects which always have a fixed length at runtime as they got compiled e.g. like this one i am using:

```
public class SearchQueryResults
   {
       public string ID { get; set; }
       public string AIRCRAFT { get; set; }
       public string DESCRIPTION { get; set; }
   }
```

But as I don't want to compile with each game patch or change my Tool again, I'd like to know if there is a way to dynamically have an object with dynamic bindings.
I tried already

```
Dictionary<object, object> plswork = new Dictionary<object, object>();
    plswork.Add("ID", ri[i].ID);
    for (int j = 1; j < MainStructure.Planes.Length; ++j)
    {
        if (ri[i].GetStateAircraft(MainStructure.Planes[i]) == PlaneState.ACTIVE)
            plswork.Add(MainStructure.Planes[i], true);
        else if(!plswork.ContainsKey(MainStructure.Planes[i]))
            plswork.Add(MainStructure.Planes[i], false);
    }
    DGAdded.Items.Add(plswork);
```

The same with <string, object> or a one dimensional array with one string followed by bools that should have the same bitlength, but yeah im stuck.
Please someone help!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the Solution is to create a DataTable and use its defaultView as ItemSource for the datagrid.

Here a small snippet, how i solved it. Happy coding everyone. Please View otherwise the linked Thread.

```
    DataTable GetEmptyDTForSelection()
    {
        System.Data.DataTable dt = new DataTable("Data");
        dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
        for (int i = 1; i < MainStructure.Planes.Length; ++i)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(MainStructure.Planes[i]+"_cb", typeof(bool));
            dt.Columns.Add(MainStructure.Planes[i]+"_desc", typeof(string));
        }

        return dt;
    }

    void RefreshDGSelected()
    {
        DGAdded.Items.Clear();
        List<RelationItem> ri = Current.AllRelations();
        System.Data.DataTable dt = GetEmptyDTForSelection();

        for (int i=0; i<ri.Count; ++i)
        {
            object[] row = new object[1 + (MainStructure.Planes.Length - 1)*2 ];
            row[0] = ri[i].ID;
            int k = 1;
            for (int j = 1; j < MainStructure.Planes.Length; ++j)
            {
                if (ri[i].GetStateAircraft(MainStructure.Planes[j]) == PlaneState.ACTIVE)
                {
                    row[k] = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    row[k] = false;
                }
                ++k;
                row[k] = ri[i].GetInputDescription(MainStructure.Planes[j]);
                ++k;                    
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        DGAdded.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
    }
```